# elasticsearch: distributing indices over multiple disk volumes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one index which is quite large (about 100Gb), so I had to extend my disk space on my digital ocean survey by adding another volume (I run everything on only one node). I told elasticsearch that it now has to consider two disk locations by

```
/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.data=/var/lib/elasticsearch,/mnt/volume-sfo2-01/es_data
```

elasticsearch does seem to have taken notice of this since it wrote some stuff to the new location

```
/mnt/volume-sfo2-01/es_data# cd nodes/
/mnt/volume-sfo2-01/es_data/nodes# ls
0
/mnt/volume-sfo2-01/es_data/nodes# cd 0/
/mnt/volume-sfo2-01/es_data/nodes/0# ls
indices  node.lock  _state
/mnt/volume-sfo2-01/es_data/nodes/0# cd indices
/mnt/volume-sfo2-01/es_data/nodes/0/indices# ls
DixLGLrJRXm1gSYcFzkzzw  nmZbce8wTayJC2s_eMC0-g  Qd-9ZnFIRoSM2z7AohKm-w  Sm_tyYTJTty0ImvDamFaQw
/mnt/volume-sfo2-01/es_data/nodes/0/indices# cd DixLGLrJRXm1gSYcFzkzzw/
/mnt/volume-sfo2-01/es_data/nodes/0/indices/DixLGLrJRXm1gSYcFzkzzw# ls
_state
```

which is identical to the stuff I find in /var/lib/elasticsearch/data, except of the actual index information in the lowest level.

Reading the elasticsearch documentary I got the impression that elasticsearch is arranging the new index over the two disk locations, but will not split a shard between the two locations. So I initialized the index with 5 shards so that it can split the data between the volumes.

The survey does seem to have detected the two data paths since the log file shows

```
[2017-06-17T19:16:57,079][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [WU6cQ-o] using [2] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/vda1), /mnt/volume-sfo2-01 (/dev/sda)]], net usable_space [29.6gb], net total_space [98.1gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
```

However, when I index the new indices, with constantly uses all the disk space on my original disk and eventually runs out of disk space with the error

```
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(500, u'index_failed_engine_exception', u'Index failed for [pubmed_paper#25949809]')
```

It never shifts one of the shards to the second volume? Do I miss anything? Can I manually guide the disk space usage?

Here are the elasticsearch version details:

```
# curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'
{
  "name" : "WU6cQ-o",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "hKc147QfQqCefLliStLNtw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.1.1",
    "build_hash" : "5395e21",
    "build_date" : "2016-12-06T12:36:15.409Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.3.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

and here is the default path file structure, where ekasticsearch stores all the information (instead of sharing it with the second path)

```
/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/DixLGLrJRXm1gSYcFzkzzw# ls
0  1  2  3  4  _state
```

one question is probably whether I can just take one of these shards and move it to the other location?

Comment: can you share what is the latest folder structure of path `nodes/0/indices/DixLGLrJRXm1gSYcFzkzzw` after you created 5 shards in your elasticsearch and which ES version you are using.

Comment: hi sumit... I added the information you ask above cheers carl

Comment: Likely related: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/16763

Comment: @carl it is clear that ES assigned all shards on one single path.data therefore it won't move to another path as it is one time thing. Did you try reducing and increasing the number of shards?

Comment: Hi Sumit... I did not try to change the number of shards. I index the documents and run out of disk space at some point. My expectation was that es would move the shards? If es does not have that capability that would, of course, explain the behavior??

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, Add a harddrive with 1TB size to your system & copy the data of 100GB to new harddrive & update your data directory location to point to new harddrive, don't give both path otherwise it will try to write data to old path too

Comment: Can you describe how I would manually move an index? I just don't want to break anything.

Comment: Step 1 : Copy the content of your data directory to new location (probably new hard disk)
Step 2 : Change your data directory path pointing to new location 
So after sometimes data will be start writing to new location..

Comment: It will take max 3-5 hours to perform copy operation over 100GB, so i think you will be up with solution in sometime...